# How do you increment a value in a DataGridView in C# if it exists in the datagrid already

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, increment, setvalue

I have this code and it does the right thing but the selector stays on the first row so it increments the quantity of the wrong entry.

I would like to search the datagrid and if there is a a match on the first column then increment the Cells[6].Value(The number of items) then find the total using the price in the Cells[3].Value then set Cells[6].Value(the total) to the product of both of these

```
  private void productCodeBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//Event that waits for a correct barcode_id to be entered in
{
    string[] itemInfo;//defines a string to hold product information coming in from the API using the getProduct method
    int quantity = 1;//sets the initial quantity to 1 as a default
    try//tries to parse any input in until a correct product code is entered else carries on checking
    {
        itemInfo = getProduct(productCodeBox.Text);//initializes the array with the product code that matches a value in the API

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in productList.Rows)//used to check if the item is in the data gridview and adds a qty instead of a whole new item
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(itemInfo[0]))//checks if the product code is already in the datagridview
                {
                    productList.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                    //Increments the qty
                    int qty = (int)productList.Rows[productList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[6].Value;//gets the current value of the quantity field in the DataGridView at the selected position
                    productList.Rows[productList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[6].Value = qty + 1;//Increments the value of the the quantity column in the datagrid view but only the first value.

                    //Gets the total of that column
                    double price = (double)productList.Rows[productList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3].Value;

                    double total = price * qty;//calculates the product
                    productList.Rows[productList.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[7].Value = total;//is meant to get the price from the total column but nothing is displayed

                    itemInfo = null;//resets the array so that the item is not duplicated
                    productCodeBox.Clear();//clears the box to wait for the next input

                } 

            }
            productList.Rows.Add(new object[] { itemInfo[0], itemInfo[1], itemInfo[2], itemInfo[3], itemInfo[4], itemInfo[5], quantity });//inserts the new value if it does not already exist
        productCodeBox.Clear();//clears the text box to wait for more input

    }
    catch(Exception a)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: Very useful if you don't want to use threading to add something perpetually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this works for you:

```
var matchedRow = productList.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(row=>row.Cells[0].Value != null &&
                                                 row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(itemInfo[0]));
if(matchedRow != null){
  int qty = (int)matchedRow.Cells[6].Value + 1;
  double price = (double)matchedRow.Cells[3].Value;
  matchedRow.Cells[7].Value = price * qty;
}
```

Comment: When I try to add another item now it does not add it to the datagridview?

Comment: @RyanSeanWattrus this code does not prevent you from adding rows, you can add it freely as normally. What is the exception? or simply the row is not added? Have you tried debug? just put the break point at the line `productList.Rows.Add(new object[]...)`

Comment: I am using the debug now and it is stuck in the loop for some reason. The qty is incrementing but not updating the datagridview?              I think it is because it is always returning a null because there are not more matches after the first value is put in?

Comment: @RyanSeanWattrus What loop? my code doesn't use any loop, you need to remove your loop and use my code instead.

Comment: Oh I see sorry, I was stil using the foreach loop. Its working now but its not updating the total?

Comment: @RyanSeanWattrus it's too strange. unless there is some `silent exception thrown`, it's also easy to debug. You can try setting some break point at the line `matchedRow.Cells[7].Value = ...`, hover the mouse over `qty` and `price`, they should show some value. Note that, the `matchedRow.Cells[7].Value = ...` **will update the total at the matched row not the current row**, you should check it again.

Comment: @RyanSeanWattrus it's possibly that there is no matched row. You should check the condition in `Equals(...)`

Comment: The problem is that the datagrid view was returning a string and it was being parsed into a double causing the line to not read it. Every thing is working now